# Paypal IPN not works for subscription

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

Paypal IPN doesnot return any variable for subscription payment, I have spent more than a week, still i haven't break the wall. I am using host gator webhosting service.

please send the the working example...thankyou
shiva@asalta.com

Comment: -1: You need to provide more details. Just saying that subscription dosent return variables is not enough. Also send some code showing what you have done so far, and state exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Paypal IPN does return variables for subscription payments, I have it working.  You need to read the 'Paypal IPN Variable Reference Guide'.  Do a google and you'll find heaps on it.

I'm developing in ruby on rails and these screencasts by Ryan Bates really helped me.  You want episodes 141, 142 and 143:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=paypal

Answer (score 0):

use sandbox account to test. register new account here http://developer.paypal.com/ and use IPN simulator. if you have specific problems maybe could update here.

Answer (score 0):

when your create subscribe button you will found that one option

click this one

**Step 3: Customize advanced features (optional)**

point 1.

Take customers to this URL when they cancel their checkout

http://yourdomain/cancel

point 2.
Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout

http://yourdomain/success

point 3.
Add advanced variables

**notify_url=http://yourdomain/paypalipn**

after define point 3 you can get PAYPAL IPN variable